# MySQL query – avoid all possible time clashes + 8 hour overlap

Tags: mysql, datetime

**Hi,**

I have a MySQL query in where I need to compare times in a WHERE clause and it really truly confuses me.

The idea is that $starttime & $endtime come from the shift I am adding someone to, and starttime and endtime in the database is what I check against.

The basic idea is that I need to find a way to not be able to double book people and they need to have had 8 hours of rest between shifts.

A shift can be any length and sometimes "within" the times of another shift.

**EXAMPLES**

Normal dayshift

- 08:00 - 20:00

Normal nightshift

- 20:00 - 08:00

Half shift within dayshift or nightshift

- 12:00 - 18:00
- 01:00 - 06:00

Overlapping times

- 08:00 - 21:00
- 20:00 - 09:00

I feel like I almost got it but there is always some scenario where it still adds the user even though they are in a shift where the times clashes or they haven't had 8 hours of rest, plus I believe the query can be much more effective.

I've tried using BETWEEN but I didn't get the hang of it.

I'm sure there are a million ways to compare and look for these clashes with INTERVAL, DATE_SUB, DATE_ADD, BETWEEN, !=, but I've been at it for too long...

```
WHERE 
  crewid = $crewid 
  AND status != 'Unavailable' 
  AND (
    (
      '$startdate' >= (startdate - INTERVAL 8 HOUR) 
      AND '$enddate' <= (enddate + INTERVAL 8 HOUR)
    ) 
    OR (
      (startdate - INTERVAL 8 HOUR) > '$startdate' 
      AND (startdate - INTERVAL 8 HOUR) < '$enddate'
    ) 
    AND '$startdate' <= enddate 
    OR enddate >= '$startdate'
  )
```

Comment: To check for intersections, you'd just need `$startdate <= enddate AND $enddate >= startdate`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. Any idea how to combine it with making sure there is 8 hours between the shifts someone can work? Meaning you shouldn't be able to work both 08:00 - 20:00 and then the following 21:00 - 09:00 or vice versa. They don't intersect but I still need a warning.

Comment: The given $startdate must not be before 8 hours after any enddate and the $enddate must not be after 8 hours before any startdate, that should be `$startdate >= date_add(enddate,  INTERVAL 8 HOUR) AND $enddate <= date_sub(startdate, INTERVAL 8 HOUR)`.

Comment: Thank you so much, but I really can't seem to put it together... The first part works but to add the interval I guess I need to figure out where to put the parathesis and either it breaks / syntax error or lets me add people anyway because it's not excuting it in the right order I suppose? Also don't know if I need AND or OR?

Comment: Depends, but I'm sorry, this is not the place for ongoing discussions and I don't think we can move to the chat, because you'd need a reputation of at least 20 to write there. I could try to give an answer, but you'd need to provide some CREATE TABLE statements, sample data and the desired output.

Comment: Actually I think I got it now! Will answer my own question and hope it helps someone else too, even if it might not be the most relatable scenario. THANK YOU for your input though! It helped me a lot!

Answer (score 1):

**Finally, it seems like this is the working solution!** Since it sometimes finds two or more clashes and I am only interested in the closest one that I am displaying I eliminate the duplicate messages by grouping them.

```
WHERE 
  crewid = $crewid 
  AND status != 'Unavailable' 
  AND (
    (
      '$startdate' <= enddate 
      AND '$enddate' >= startdate
    ) 
    OR (
      '$startdate' <= DATE_ADD(enddate, INTERVAL 8 HOUR) 
      AND '$enddate' >= DATE_SUB(startdate, INTERVAL 8 HOUR)
    )
  ) 
GROUP BY 
  crewid
```